# Worst case using the first fit $2$-approximation for the bin packing problem

Tags: optimization, np-hard, approximation

I am with the phone so I would be more verbose when I will have a pc on hand, if you desire.

The first fit algorithm for approximating the bin packing problem (NP-hard) is a $2$-approximation for the optimum. Can you show me a concrete worst case showing that $2$ is a good (or bad) extimate for the bound?

Comment: That's a nice exercise that is best done on your own. Try a few examples, or go through the analysis of the first fit algorithm and see what would have to happen for it to be tight.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus will I be able to get exactly $2$ or something smaller?

Comment: Not necessarily exactly 2, but $2-\epsilon$ for any positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, no idea, can you give me an hint please?

Comment: I also have no idea, but fortunately it's not my exercise.

Comment: It is not an exercise, it is a question for curiosity sake. Honestly I do not think it is possibile to get $2-\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$. I think that the bound is tighter. And also I do not think the solution is trivial.

Comment: Ok I have just found that it is highly non trivial, see this http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2013/3963/pdf/51.pdf

Comment: Yes, just found the same paper. This suggests that next time, before asking a question here you spend a few minutes trying to find an existing answer yourself on the internet.

Comment: Ok, but I can tell the same to you regarding your first comment.

Comment: Fair enough. I guessed that it's an easy homework question that you were having trouble with, but in this case my guess was wrong. Unfortunately many of the questions here are of the former type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approximation ratio of first fit for bin packing is actually 1.7 rather than 2. See Dósa and Sgall, [First fit bin packing: a tight analysis](http://iuuk.mff.cuni.cz/~sgall/ps/FFabs.pdf). The paper contains references which prove a matching lower bound.

Comment: The question is about the concrete example of the worst-case. If the paper gives it, could you point to that?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the paper?

Comment: Yep. Although I have not read it it in detail. It is clear that ratio is 1.7, but the concrete example of an input is not that obvious. Pardon me, if I missed it. But would you mind updating your answer including such input example?

Comment: I can do no better than read the paper, which you can also do.

Comment: The lower bounds are in Section 4, which also points at two earlier papers.

Comment: So, no example input, I assume?

Comment: The example input is there. You'll have to read it yourself. It's essentially given in Lemma 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you can check yourself that the approximation ratio will be better than 2: Assume you have items that can be fit into k bins, each bin having capacity one. So far you have used 2k-1 bins, so you want to prove that the next item fits into one of the 2k-1 bins.

Let the next item have size c. We have c ≤ 1/2: If c was greater than 0.5, then we would have 2k items > 0.5 for a total size > k,  which couldn't fit into k bits.

And there is a bin that contains at most 1 - c so the next item fits into that bin: Otherwise, we have 2k-1 bins containing > 1-c ≥ 1/2, so we have more than 2k-2 bins containing 1/2, 1 bin containing more than 1-c, plus an item of size c, for a total > k. This doesn't fit into k bins.

Comment: When we say that the approximation ratio is better than 2, we meant that the algorithm is a $c$-approximation for some $c < 2$. It's not enough that we always get a solution which is better than twice the optimum. In other words, the approximation ratio is a *supremum* that isn't necessarily achieved.